# Formatting a date column in powerpointwriter

Tags: powerpoint, officewriter

I am using PowerpointWriter to populate a ppt table.  I have currency and date columns that need to be formatted (not with colors/fonts/etc).  For example, the date column needs to be the date only, not the time.

How do I do this?

Thanks,
Cheri

Answer (score 0):

PowerPointWriter does not support that kind of formatting at the moment. You should consider formatting your data in your application before binding the data to the PowerPoint file using PowerPointWriter..